# Attach to Visual Studio process by name

Tags: visual-studio

For the development I do, I often need to attach to a running process by name (usually a windows service running under a different user account). It is tedious to do:

```
Debug
Attach to Process...
Select Attach To to switch between Native and Managed code
    (we use both in the same process so it's not set to automatic)
Scroll down to find it in the list
Hit Attach button
Agree to the confirmation to debug a windows service
```

Since it's always the same process, ideally I would like 2 buttons (macros?) on a custom toolbar. One that attaches for managed debugging and another that attaches for native debugging. In both cases, the process name is built into the macro.

Can someone point me to the right resources/documentation to set something like that up?

Comment: Have you tried using [gflags](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/824344)?

Comment: This *is* annoying.  I haven't had to debug services, etc., but even attaching to the same process again and again is tedious.  It seems reasonable that the dialog could remember the name of the process you attached to most recently and offer that as the default the next time.  Maybe this needs a feature request to Microsoft.

Comment: The techniques for debugging services can still be applied, and the debugger can be any you choose, IIRC

Comment: thanks Rowland. I'll read through the link you gave this evening.

Comment: also, I realize that technically, it's <custom-shortcut-key-for-attach-to-process> (dialog opens, process list is focused) <first letter of process name>, <enter>... The verbose description above is just an expressing of frustration. I'd still like to build a macro.

Answer (score 2):

A Visual Studio macro that you can customize for your process name:
[Attach the VS Debugger to IIS’s Worker Process in a single keystroke](http://geekswithblogs.net/SoftwareDoneRight/archive/2009/10/30/quicktip--attach-the-vs-debugger-to-iisrsquos-worker-process.aspx).

[Debug Attach Manager 2012](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/19951adf-722a-4d92-a73a-6d7a3d70cfc4) extension for VS 2012 that "provides extended abilities to attach Visual Studio debuger to web application pools, windows services and other processes."